# An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in sessions#new: activeadmin couldn't find file 'active_admin/nested_menu_arrow.gif'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin, actionview

After updgrading from Rails 5.0.1 to 5.2.0, there was an upgrade in active admin (from 1.0.0.pre5 to 2.6.0)
Now I am getting :

```
An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in sessions#new:

  couldn't find file 'active_admin/nested_menu_arrow.gif'
Checked in these paths:
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/app/assets/images
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/app/assets/javascripts
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/app/assets/stylesheets
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/lazy_high_charts-1.4.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-ef1faccaef75/app/assets/javascripts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-ef1faccaef75/app/assets/stylesheets
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-ef1faccaef75/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/formtastic-3.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /mnt/d/Project/Wittybrains/Optisom/clarityv2/app/assets/fonts
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.5.0/assets/stylesheets
  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.5.0/assets/fonts
  app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss:9
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging on Google, finally I found this link :

> https://git.rarolabs.com.br/rarolabs/active_admin/tree/1a16239be31d40307f3fee972e91ca15b9341167/app/assets/images/active_admin

What I did, I downloaded the necessary resources and keep in my project path at corresponding locations. This solves the issues.